# Selecting facebook button webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I've tried everything to select this facebook button, by css, by partial link, by xpath. Can someone show me the syntax? HTML Code is below, the element is highlighted in blue.

This is the html for facebook Iframe login

```
 <html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
<title>My Photo Tab</title>
<base href="/">
<script src="https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.U-RewQuh4JY.O/m=signin_annotation/exm=client,plusone/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCNj6EO7Q-0o28iG5EwDca54BMQrpw/t=zcms/cb=gapi.loaded_2" async="">
<script src="https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.U-RewQuh4JY.O/m=plusone/exm=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCNj6EO7Q-0o28iG5EwDca54BMQrpw/t=zcms/cb=gapi.loaded_1" async="">
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit_main.js">
<script id="adblade-sdk" src="http://web.adblade.com/js/ads/async/show.js">
<script id="facebook-jssdk" src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js">
<script id="google-platform-js" src="http://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" gapi_processed="true">
<script id="twitter-wjs" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js">
<script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js">
<script src="https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.U-RewQuh4JY.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCNj6EO7Q-0o28iG5EwDca54BMQrpw/t=zcms/cb=gapi.loaded_0" async="">
<script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css?gb=0.0.3">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery.simplecolorpicker.css?gb=0.0.3">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css?gb=0.0.3">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/shared.css?gb=0.0.3">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/home.index.css?gb=0.0.3">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/home.modals.css?gb=0.0.3">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/languageSize.css?gb=0.0.3">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/chosen/chosen.min.css?gb=0.0.3">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/lp2.css?gb=0.0.3">
<meta content="http://myphototab.com" property="og:url">
<meta content="Your social photos on your new tab page!" property="og:title">
<meta content="http://cdn.myphototab.com/content/images/social.jpg" property="og:image">
<meta content="My Photo Tab" property="og:site_name">
<meta content="Turn your browser's boring new tab page into your personalized photo gallery!" property="og:description">
<meta content="summary_large_image" name="twitter:card">
<meta content="MyPhotoTab" name="twitter:site">
<meta content="MyPhotoTab" name="twitter:creator">
<meta content="Your social photos on your new tab page!" name="twitter:title">
<meta content="Turn your browser's boring new tab page into your personalized photo gallery!" name="twitter:description">
<meta content="http://cdn.myphototab.com/content/images/social.jpg" name="twitter:image:src">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://staticd.cdn.adblade.com/css/zones/zone1101.css">
<style type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js">
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://b.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js?c1=8&c2=6864322&c3=&c4=&c5=&c6=&c10=&c15=">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://staticd.cdn.adblade.com/css/zones/zone1101.css">
<style type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js">
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://b.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js?c1=8&c2=6864322&c3=&c4=&c5=&c6=&c10=&c15=">
<style type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
</head>
<body class="isFF isWindows loggedout page-loaded modal-open Large en" style="background-image: none; background-color: rgb(192, 192, 192); overflow-y: auto;" data-twttr-rendered="true">
<input id="IsFromExtension" type="hidden" value="true">
<div class="pageWrapper" ng-view="">
<section id="homeView">
<div class="container body-content" style="">
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade in" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" style="display: block; visibility: visible;">
<div onload="showModal()" ng-include="partialUrl.Base">
<div id="modalWelcome" class="modal-dialog" style="display: block;">
<div class="modal-content gray-border">
<button class="close" ng-click="welcomeClose({trackingData: ['2', 'index-welcome', 'welcome-popup-close', '']})" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
<div class="modal-body" style="">
<div class="modal-body-inner">
<div class="language">
<div class="title center langDir" style="direction: ltr;">
<div class="subtitle2 center langDir" translate="" style="direction: ltr;">My Photo Tab allows you to see your social and other photos on your browser's new tab page - FREE!</div>
<div class="socialButtons">
<div class="socialButtonsInner">
<div class="fblogin">
<fblogin>
<div class="fbLoginInner">
<fb:login-button class=" fb_iframe_widget" onlogin="FacebookLoginState();" scope="public_profile,email,user_photos,user_friends,publish_actions" size="xlarge" login_text=" Login with Facebook " fb-xfbml-state="rendered" fb-iframe-plugin-query="app_id=860682337328409&container_width=147&locale=en_US&login_text=%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Login%20with%20Facebook%0A%20%20%20%20&scope=public_profile%2Cemail%2Cuser_photos%2Cuser_friends%2Cpublish_actions&sdk=joey&size=xlarge">
<span style="vertical-align: bottom; width: 290px; height: 39px;">
<iframe class="" width="1000px" height="1000px" frameborder="0" name="f138e5757ce176" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" title="fb:login_button Facebook Social Plugin" style="border: medium none; visibility: visible; width: 290px; height: 39px;" src="http://www.facebook.com/v2.1/plugins/login_button.php?app_id=860682337328409&channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2F6Dg4oLkBbYq.js%3Fversion%3D41%23cb%3Df135579120b2446%26domain%3Dmyphototab.com%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fmyphototab.com%252Ff21d55794e16b1c%26relation%3Dparent.parent&container_width=147&locale=en_US&login_text=%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Login%20with%20Facebook%0A%20%20%20%20&scope=public_profile%2Cemail%2Cuser_photos%2Cuser_friends%2Cpublish_actions&sdk=joey&size=xlarge">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="facebook" class="" lang="en">
<head>
<body class="plugin gecko win x1 Locale_en_US" dir="ltr">
<div class="_li">
<div class="pluginSkinLight pluginFontHelvetica">
<div id="u_0_0" class="pluginLoginButton pluginLoginButtonXlarge" style="width: 300px;">
<div>
<div id="u_0_1" class="_4z_b _4z_8 _4z_c" tabindex="0" role="button">
<table class="uiGrid _51mz" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr class="_51mx">
<td class="_51m-">
<td class="_51m- _51mw">
<span class="_4z_9">
<span class="_4z_f fwb">Login with Facebook</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First switch to the iframe using: **(As Saifur told name seems to be dynamic hence identifying element based on title)**

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@title,'Facebook Social Plugin')]")));
```

then click on the span as

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Login with Facebook')]"))).click();
```

Comment: tried your method still no success. How can this issue be resolved in the future? Is this just bad developing? Should they create an ID for it?

Comment: Yes. This seems to be an issue with `iframe`

Comment: @Elsid it would be better if you could provide the complete page HTML...there must be some other glitch in ur webpage.

Answer (score 1):

Try `xpath` text based search

```
//span[contains(text(),'Login with Facebook')]
```

However, depending on the element load time you may need to add some `explicit` wait as well.

```
By xpath = By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Login with Facebook')]");
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(xpath));
myDynamicElement.click();
```

**Edit**

Just saw that page contains `iframe`. So, you need to use `switchTo()` to set focus into `iframe` before start looking for the element. See the [API doc](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html#frame%28int%29)

```
//Looks like the name of ifame is also dynamic 
//driver.switchTo().frame("fbf1ab674");
//assuming that's the only iframe on
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('iframe')));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Login with Facebook')]")).click();
//switch back to default content when done working inside iframe
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

I suspect for the same reason `linkText` and `cssSelector` you have used did not work.

Also, please try to post `html` instead of image for future reference which is much easier to read and find possible issues.

Comment: I have added a 10 second pause before i proceed, tried your path still didn't find it.

Comment: I tried that a time before, thought maybe i had the wrong syntax, but i tried your way again, still didn't accept it. I added more html code above the iframe maybe it helps, check my main edited post.

Comment: And, seems like the name of the iframe is also dynamic. I saw a different name before. So taking @vivek's concept switch to iframe using xpath or css. See my edit

Comment: Yeah i noticed it was dynamic it seemed like so i changed it to the new value, still didn't work. I also tried your method didn't work. Is their a resource which shows us syntax for locating by xpath/css different elements? It seems we all have a different syntax for locating the same thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74145/discussion-between-saifur-and-elsid).

Answer (score 1):

That's no button, that's a span.

Try: `//span[text()='Login with Facebook']`

Comment: i tried this one before, tried it again still couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

With Firefox (firebug) and Chrome (chromebug), u can copy the xpath of each selected item. Very useful when developing with Selenium!

Check out this wikihow page and u will like it!

http://m.wikihow.com/Find-XPath-Using-Firebug

Meanwhile it should also be available in Firefox inspector.

Comment: What WebDriver implementation? Did you print the page-source through the WebDriver? Maybe it has rendered in another way as your browser did.

Comment: No I just copied through firebug the xpath and css path